# connect to avd/logcat via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, logcat, android-virtual-device

Is there any way of connecting my actual device to avd and/or especially to logcat via **bluetooth**? googleing it didn't yield anything so if anyone has an idea please share!

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your goal is to be able to connect your device wirelessly to the adb server, this [blog post](http://www.chentir.com/?p=1613) (that I wrote) will answer your question.

***TL;DR, you need to switch the ADB transport mode from USB to TCPIP.***

The steps are:

- Grap the IP address of the device, by doing:

> adb shell netcfg

- Switch to TCPIP mode:

> adb tcpip 5555 (or any port number between 5555 and 5585

- Stop adb server

> adb kill-server

- Set ADBHOST to your IP address

> ADBHOST= adb devices

Note that if you change your keywords to: set adb in TCP/IP mode you will probably find a lot of resources, like [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp) or this [XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=623828&page=3).